# How do I configure Thunderbird to send plain text emails by default?

Tags: thunderbird

Title pretty much says it all.  I want to tell Thunderbird to edit and send emails in plain text by default.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As @enzotib pointed out in the comment, this is set up in the Account Options, under "Composition and Addressing"

[image: Thunderbird Tools -> Account Settings screenshot]

Then Thunderbird will compose emails in plain text. To switch from plain text for one email to HTML, hold shift while you click on Reply, Forward, or compose and it will let you compose in HTML.

Comment: The problem I have found with this is that it seems to lock you at plain text, so you have to go in and change the setting every time you want to do an HTML email. Is there a way to allow you to compose in both but pick plain text by default?

Comment: That is what I have found as well - if anyone does find a way to do that PLEASE let us know!

Comment: I found a workaround and have just updated the answer

Comment: Note that if you have additional identities for one account, you might want to change the preference for all of them: "Account settings" -> select account -> "Manage identities" -> select identity and press "Edit" -> "Composition & Addressing" -> uncheck "Compose messages in HTML format"

Comment: Formatting may also be set in Menu -> Options -> Delivery Format.

Answer (score 2):

To stop Mozilla Thunderbird from asking you about the desired format when you compose a rich text message and click Send:

1. Select `Tools` - `Options` (or `Thunderbird` - `Preferences` ... on a Mac) from the menu.
2. Go to the `Composition` category.
3. Make sure the `General` tab is selected.
4. Click `Send Options`...
5. Under `Text Format`, make sure something like `Ask me what to do` is NOT selected.

I recommend Send the message in both plain text and HTML, which preserves any rich formatting while giving recipients a chance to choose a plain text alternative.